# PushViewController to current navigation controller from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating a class object from my UIViewController and trying to push a controller from it,  and it won't work.

I have been doing research but found nothing, any idea?

---

```
@implementation ViewController
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.newClass = [[MyNewClass alloc] init];
  self.newClass.view = self.view;
  self.newClass.navigationController = self.navigationController;
  [self.newClass connect];
}
...
@end
```

---

MyNewClass.h

```
@interface MyNewClass : NSObject<UINavigationControllerDelegate>
  @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *view;
  @property(nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
  -(void) connect;
@end
```

---

MyNewClass.m

```
-(void)connect
{
 OtherViewController * otherVC =
                             [[OtherViewController alloc] init];


  self.navigationController pushViewController:otherVC animated:YES];
} 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

add folloeing code into appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and then remove all other UINavigationController declaration and allocation. Like MyNewClass's NavigationVontroller. Because here you declare and allocate navigationcontroller in appdelegate so you can use it in whole app.

Comment: The question is how you get a reference to the navigation controller, not how you create it.

Answer (score 0):

When `viewDidLoad` is called, the view has just been loaded but the view controller hasn't necessarily been added to a navigation controller yet. So using `viewDidLoad` as your trigger is not useful.

A better approach is to explicitly pass the navigation controller to the view controller when it's created. Or to implement `didMoveToParentViewController:` and do your configuration there.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a viewController from a controller, which is not a part of navigationController, so first make it part of navigationController, then try